# Django trouble collecting static using Whitenoise and pushing to Heroku - Getting UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, static, django-staticfiles

Before Installing Whitenoise, I could collect static and everything works perfect locally, but after installing Whitenoise and attempting to push my files to heroku for production, I got the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/static/static'
```

I then attempted to collect static through my terminal to troubleshoot and got this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I'm new, and it's tough to understand where to start to troubleshoot this. I tried messing around with my static directory settings with no luck, but it seems that the location is fine, but whitenoise is failing to collect anything because of this Unicode error and that's why I can't push it to Heroku. I'm unsure of how to figure out where this error is located from the traceback, or how to fix it. Here is the full traceback:

```
     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Jup\PycharmProjects\Landing\Gas\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Jup\PycharmProjects\Landing\Gas\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Jup\PycharmProjects\Landing\Gas\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Jup\PycharmProjects\Landing\Gas\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Jup\PycharmProjects\Landing\Gas\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 189, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "C:\Users\Jup\PycharmProjects\Landing\Gas\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 129, in collect
    for original_path, processed_path, processed in processor:
  File "C:\Users\Jup\PycharmProjects\Landing\Gas\lib\site-packages\whitenoise\storage.py", line 67, in post_process
    for name, hashed_name, processed in files:
  File "C:\Users\Jup\PycharmProjects\Landing\Gas\lib\site-packages\whitenoise\storage.py", line 29, in post_process_with_compression
    for name, hashed_name, processed in files:
  File "C:\Users\Jup\PycharmProjects\Landing\Gas\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 405, in post_process
    yield from super().post_process(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jup\PycharmProjects\Landing\Gas\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 239, in post_process
    for name, hashed_name, processed, _ in self._post_process(paths, adjustable_paths, hashed_files):
  File "C:\Users\Jup\PycharmProjects\Landing\Gas\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 290, in _post_process
    content = original_file.read().decode(settings.FILE_CHARSET)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

And here are the Whitenoise settings in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Here is my directory structure:

```
Virtual ENV\
        Project\
                APP\
                     templates\
                source\
                     settings.py
                manage.py
                .env
                Pipfile.lock
        static\
                media\
                static\
                static-only\
```

If you all could help me figure out if I have my directory / static settings incorrectly configured for deployment, and how to locate and fix the Uincode error that would be awesome!

Comment: try to add `FILE_CHARSET = 'utf-16'` in `settings.py`

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta Unfortunately that did not work. When I tried to run the server it couldn't decode using that setting. The encoding only came before when I tried to collect static. Anything else you can think of?